# How to ignore <td> inside column data - datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a function that opens a excel application and populated the excel with the data present in datatables. Everything works fine until the data contains `<td>` in them, in that case the data is not written in proper format (since it assumes that the `<td>` present inside the column data is a datatable column).

This is the function I use to create a excel document.

```
$(dTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
$(this.nTr).each(function (c) {
var nTds = $('td', this);
for (var j = 0; j < nTds.length; j++) {
excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1).Value = $(nTds[j]).text();
};
i = i + 1;
});
```

Is there a way to get `<TD>` of just the datatables column and not other td's?

Comment: have you considered using `<tbody>`?

Comment: What about something like this? (don't trust calling it answer, but it is a guess)  

`$(dTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {  
$(this.nTr).each(function (c) {  
var nTds = $('td', this);  
for (var j = 0; j < nTds.length; j++) {  
var text=$(nTds[j]).text();
var text=text.replace(/\<td\>/g,'\<td\>').replace(/\<\/td\>/g,'\<\/td\>'););  
excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1).Value = $(nTds[j]).text();  
};  
i = i + 1;  
});  `

Comment: Sorry that that is so messy.  I was trying to figure out how to format it better, but then SO stopped letting me edit the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dTable.$("tr").each(function(i, data){
    $(data).find("td").each(function(j, innerData){
        excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1).Value = $(innerData).text();
    });
});
```

or

```
dTable.$("tr").each(function(i, data){
    $(data).children().each(function(j, innerData){
        excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1).Value = $(innerData).text();
    });
});
```